# How can I run docker-compose commands from a dynamically started compose command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Because of using multiple micro-services, with each micro-service having their own database dependencies (some overlap). I have a custom bash file that allows the developer to choose which microservices they want to run locally (for testing), it essentially builds a command:

EDIT: thanks to answer pointing out, you do need `-f` before every compose `.yml` file, I do use this, I just didn't originally type it out here.

```sh
docker-compose -f \
-f <docker-compose.ms1.yml> -f <docker-compose.ms2.yml> \
-f <docker-compose.dba> -f <docker-compose.dbb> \
up ms1-container ms2-container \
dba-container dbb container
```

Now this works fine, but traditionally (using a single `.yml` file and just running `docker-compose up`), if I wanted to see output logs, I would do `docker-compose logs -f`, or if I wanted to restart a particular service in the compose file, I would:

```sh
docker-compose stop <service_name>
docker-compose rm <service_name>
docker-compose create <service_name>
docker-compose start <service_name>
```

But now with it all started dynamically, how can I restart a particular docker-compose service, and also how can I tap back into the logs with `logs -f`?

Comment: docker logs -f <Container_name> schould do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think your `docker-compose` command not valid, it should be:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose_1.yaml -f docker-compose_2.yaml up -d
```

Then, everything is same with the one you just use one `docker-compose.yaml`:

E.g.

**docker-compose_1.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: alpine
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"
```

**docker-compose_2.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    image: alpine
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"
```

You can still use `docker-compose -f docker-compose_1.yaml -f docker-compose_2.yaml stop frontend` to stop one service:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/77$ docker-compose -f docker-compose_1.yaml -f docker-compose_2.yaml ps
    Name             Command         State     Ports
----------------------------------------------------
77_backend_1    tail -f /dev/null   Up
77_frontend_1   tail -f /dev/null   Exit 137
```

For logs, `docker-compose -f docker-compose_1.yaml -f docker-compose_2.yaml logs` for all service, while `docker-compose -f docker-compose_1.yaml -f docker-compose_2.yaml logs backend` for one service.

Reference to [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#specifying-multiple-compose-files):

> You can supply multiple -f configuration files. When you supply multiple files, Compose combines them into a single configuration. Compose builds the configuration in the order you supply the files. Subsequent files override and add to their predecessors.

Comment: Wow, didn't think of doing that, I am running a lot of containers right now that I can't close down to check. When I am free later, I will double check it works fine and accept you answer, thanks!